# Switching between Anaconda and Anaconda3 when creating environments

Tags: python, anaconda

I have Anaconda and Anaconda3 on my mac. I understand that Anaconda is for python 2 and Anaconda3 is for python3 (correct me if I am wrong).

I am developing in python3 but when creating environments, they go to `/anaconda/envs/` not `/anaconda3/envs/`. How to switch to anaconda3 when creating environments?

You may be in the mood to extend your answer to cover the following:

1- What are The implication of having both anaconda's in my machine. Do I need to use Anaconda when developing on python2 and Anaconda3 when developing in python3?

2- Will it make a difference if I create environments in anaconda and specify python3 when creating them.

3- Why they are located in two different locations on mac (Anaconda is located in `Machintosh HD` while Anaconda3 is located in `Users/username/')

Comment: AFAIK you should only have one install of anaconda, and use envs if you want to be able to run both 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Anaconda directory, whether it is version 2.x or 3.x, is named during installation and does not need to reflect the version. I suggest uninstalling whatever version you use less and rely on environments instead.

You can create a Python 2.7 environment with Anaconda like this:

```
conda create --name py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```